# I want to create a bit of text that changes its font at random intervals in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I attempted using a java-script loop that updated a string containing the name of the font and then use getElementById to update the font of the text, I don't really know of another way to do this. any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add your code what you already have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

[The setInterval() method repeats a given function at every given time-interval.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

[The fontFamily property sets or returns a list of font-family names and/or generic-family names for text in an element.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontstyle.asp)

```html
    <p id="myP">Click "Try it". Wait 3 seconds, the font family will be changed.</p>

    <button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction(), 3000);">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myP").style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
    }

</script>
```